# Selective tests from command line for Python unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

My project has some tests that are not intended to run by default, but I'd like to make them runnable through passing something to CLI.

When testing Python core modules we can use something like:

```
python -m test -u largefile,network
```

I'd like to have something similar for unittest, i.e.:

```
python -m unittest  # something arguments that turn on flagged tests
```

Unfortunately unittest doesn't seem to provide such argument.

Does someone has an idea to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't the [`-k` option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-options) what you are looking for?

Comment: You could name the tests in such a way that a non-default discover `--pattern` would find them.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery Or you could set an environment variable and combine this with a `skipif` condition https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called testmarker in pypi, I think it answers what you need
https://pypi.org/project/testmarker/

Comment: Can you provide more description about how to solve the problem with it?